# Spark SQL import from CSV not showing results

Tags: sql, database, azure, databricks

I created a table in Databricks using the spark sql library importing the data over a mount I created in using Azure Blob Storage. THe output shows OK but when getting the data no info is in the table.

```
`%sql

CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS csv_db.circuits(circuitId INT,
  circuitRef STRING,
  name STRING,
  location STRING,
  country STRING,
  lat DOUBLE,
  lng DOUBLE,
  alt INT,
  url STRING
)
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "mnt/testdllg/bloby/raw/circuits.csv")`
```

Comment: Usually mount paths need to start with "/". Have you tried select * from csv.\`mnt/testdllg/bloby/raw/circuits.csv\` and select * from csv.\`/mnt/testdllg/bloby/raw/circuits.csv\` And made sure the mount actually exists, checking dbutils.fs.mounts()?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of giving the path in the format below:

```sql
OPTIONS (path "mnt/testdllg/bloby/raw/circuits.csv")
```

You should use the format below to read data from an SQL table:

```sql
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/mnt/testdllg/bloby/raw/circuits.csv")
```

Then you will be able to read the data successfully by using a SELECT query as shown below:

[image]

Here is the sample code for your reference:

```sql
%sql
CREATE TABLE Students(Id int, Name varchar(20))
USING CSV
OPTIONS (path "dbfs:/mnt/files/samp.csv")
```

Along with that, make sure the mount path is correct by running the `display(dbutils.fs.mounts())` command:

[image]